# Why does pressing 'Numpad .' not center my view correctly on the selected object?

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

In layout mode, when I select my object and press numpad . to center my view onto my object. Instead it has me orbit nothing and I cant zoom in on my object. this function still works for other objects in the same scene.

Comment: The center of view is based on an object's bounding box, not the mean location of its vertices.  In the object's properties > Viewport Display panel, check 'Bounds'. That may help find a stray part of the object, perhaps a single vertex,  which is throwing it.

Answer (score 3):

In your Layout or Modeling viewport, drag out the 'Item, Tool, View' menu from the top right hand of the viewport (has a tiny little arrow pointing toward the viewport, usually to the right of the x y z orientation gizmo). In that drag-out menu, select the 'View' tab and check the 'Lock to Object' text box. If there's something listed there, hit 'X' to the right of it. Now it shouldn't orbit around another point. At least, that was the genesis of my numpad - . issue.